# Read Data from txt file and store it in hashmap keys and values

Tags: java, hashmap, file-handling

I have data which is full name  for eg. ganesh kale , abhi nale , etc.  This Data is in txt file which I have to read the file by file handling and store Data in HashMap in format of key should first name and value should be last name.

I tried something but  I dont get how to split string (eg. Ganesh kale) how I put "ganesh" in key and put "kale" in values so when I print HashMap I should get First name as a key and last name as a value

```
package javap;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Datainput {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File("E:\\Data.txt");
        file.createNewFile();

        HashMap < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String > ();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String key = s.substring(s.indexOf(" ")).trim();
            String value = s.substring(s.indexOf(" ")).trim();
            map.put(key, value);
            //System.out.println(s);

        }
        for (String a: map.KeySet()) {
            System.out.println(a + map.get(a));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this file.createNewFile(); will create new file if each file line contain something like that ganesh kale  then you can use [split(" ")](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and put first element the returned array in the key and the second one into the value

Answer (score 0):

To split a string you can use the `split()` function.

To set the first part of split string as a key and assign the second part of a split string as a value, you can do following:

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
String s = "John Doe";
map.put(s.split(" ")[0], s.split(" ")[1]);
```

Also, as far as I know, you can't have duplicate keys in a map. When trying to add an entry with duplicate key, the value of an existing entry will be overwritten.